# por que mi input submit no responde?

Tags: php, html

tengo un formulario pero mi boton submit no responde a pesar que le doy  funcion para que lleve los datos a otra pagina, no hace nada

**todo el codigo**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0 , maximum-scale=1.0 , minimum-scale=1.0"> 
                <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>ASPATPERU-SISBIO</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/default.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/component.css"/> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/demo.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style2.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilo_esquema_mdr.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">

    }

   $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("input[name=ta]").click(function () {    
       var taop =  $('input:radio[name=ta]:checked').val();

       if(taop=="1"){

          $("#targa").fadeIn("slow");
       }else if (taop=="2"){
            $("#targa").hide("slow");
       }

    });
});

 $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("input[name=tp]").click(function () {    
       var taop =  $('input:radio[name=tp]:checked').val();

       if(taop=="1"){

          $("#tpc").fadeIn("slow");
       }else if (taop=="2"){
            $("#tpc").hide("slow");
       }

    });
});

  $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("input[name=ma]").click(function () {    
       var taop =  $('input:radio[name=ma]:checked').val();

       if(taop=="1"){

          $("#nom_anti").fadeIn("slow");
       }else if (taop=="2"){
            $("#nom_anti").hide("slow");
       }

    });
});

    </script>


  <script type="text/javascript">

    function guardarf1(){

      $.ajax({
       type : "POST",
       url : "guardardetmdr.php",
       data : $("#fromulariof1").serialize(),
       success : function(data){
               $("#resultado").html(data);
              $("#resultado").show("slow");
              $("#formulario_esquema").hide("slow");
              $("#formulario_esquemamdr").show("slow");

       }

      })

      return false;

    }


     function guardarmdr1(){

      $.ajax({
       type : "POST",
       url : "traguardarmdr1.php",
       data : $("#fromulariomdr").serialize(),
       success : function(data){
               $("#resultadomdr").html(data);


       }

      })

      return false;

    }






   </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">




    function obtenerfechafinmdr(){


        var trtduracionmdr = document.getElementById("tiempomdr").value; 
        var fechainiciomdr1 = document.getElementById("infechainimdr").value   

         if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
           } else { // code for IE6, IE5
               xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
           }       

       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("fecha_fin1mdr").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","obtenerfecchafinmdr1.php?fechaini="+fechainiciomdr1+"&duracion="+trtduracionmdr,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

    }







  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">





</script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>3

    <script src="../js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>

      <style type="text/css">
                     .ca-menu .esquema_tratamiento{
                  background: #D5FFBB;
                     }
      </style>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Terminal+Dosis' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />


  </head>
  <body>

  <img class="bannerimg" src="../img/portadainicio.jpg"/>


        <div class="container" >    
            <div class="main clearfix">
                <nav id="menu" class="nav">                 
                    <ul>
                            <li>
                            <a href="../inicio.php?codcentro=<?php echo $codcentro; ?>">
                                <span id=primero class="icon">
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-home"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Principal</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <a href="paciente_incio.php?codcentro=<?php echo $codcentro; ?>">
                                <span id="segundo" class="icon"> 
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-stethoscope"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Pacientes</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span id="tercero" class="icon">
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-paste"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Reporte</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span id="cuarto" class="icon">
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-group"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Ayuda</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span id="sexto" class="icon">
                                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-contact"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span>Contact</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /container -->


<div id="contenedor_esquema">




<div id="formulario_esquema">

    <form id="fromulariof1" onsubmit="return guardarf1();" method="POST">
             <legend>DATOS DEL PACIENTE: <?php echo $apellidop.' '.$apellidom.' '.$nombre.'&nbsp&nbsp|&nbsp&nbsp'.$tipo_tratamiento;?></legend>


<?php 

 $resultado_tipotuberculosis = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM localizacion_enfermedad");
  $resultado_localizacion = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM especificacion_localizacion");
  $resultado_comorbilidad = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM comorbilidad")
 ?>

  <div class="campo_formularios1">
             <input type="hidden"  name ="dni" id="dni" value=<?php echo $dni?>>
             <input type="hidden" name="nro_caso" id="nro_caso" value=<?php echo $nro_caso?>>
               <input type="hidden" name="nombre" id="nombre" value=<?php echo $nombre?>>
             <input type="hidden" name="apellidom" id="apellidom" value=<?php echo $apellidom?>>
             <input type="hidden" name="apellidop" id="apellidop" value=<?php echo $apellidop?>>
             <input type="hidden" name="tipo_tratamiento" id="tipo_tratamiento" value=<?php echo $tipo_tratamiento?>>
             <input type="hidden" name="centro" value=<?php echo $codcentro?>>


 <select class="tipo_tuberculosis" id="tipo_tuberculosis" name="tipo_tuberculosis" onchange="mostrarespe()">
               <option value="0" disabled selected>LOCALIZACION</option>
                  <?php  
                   while ($rowtitu = $resultado_tipotuberculosis -> fetch_array()) 
                   {

                   ?>

          <option value="<?php echo $rowtitu['cod_localizacion_enf']; ?>"><?php echo $rowtitu['nombre_localizacion'];  ?></option>
          <?php
               }

            ?>

              </select>  
            <div id="especicar" >
              <select type="hidden" class="localizacion" id="localizacion" name="localizacion" onchange="mostrarespeotros();">
              <option value="0" disabled selected>ESPECIFICAR</option>
              <OPTION value="1">PLEURAL</OPTION>
              <OPTION value="4">GANGLIONAR</OPTION>
              <OPTION value="5">OSTEOARTICULAR</OPTION>
              <OPTION value="5">SISTEMA NERVIOSO CENTRAL</OPTION>
              <OPTION value="6">MILIAR</OPTION>
              <OPTION value="7">OTROS</OPTION>

              </select><br>

                 <input type="hide" name="otroses" id="otroses" style="
    margin-bottom: 10px; display: none;">
             </div>

<!--
              <select class="comorbilidad" id="comobilidad"  name="comobilidad" onchange="vervih();">
               <option value="0" disabled selected >Comorbilidad</option>
                   <?php
                       while($rowcom = $resultado_comorbilidad -> fetch_array())
                       {
                     ?>

                     <option value="<?php echo $rowcom['cod_comobilidad']; ?>"><?php echo $rowcom['nombre_comorbilidad'];  ?></option>

                     <?php
                          }
                       ?>
              </select><br>
-->
                   <input type="hide" id="otroscom" name="otroscom" id="otroscom" style="
    margin-bottom: 10px; display: none;"><br>

        <div id="mujer_edad" <?php if($sexo=='1'){ ?> style="display: none" <?php } ?> >
                <label>MUJER EN EDAD REPRODUCTIVA: &nbsp&nbsp</label>SI&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" id="mrsi" name="mr" value="1">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspNO <input type="radio" id="mrno" name="mr" value="2">  
        </div>
              <label>USA METODO ANTICONCEPTIVO &nbsp&nbsp 
              &nbsp&nbsp</label>SI <input type="radio" id="masi" name="ma" value="1">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspNO <input type="radio" id="mano" name="ma" value="2"><br>
              <input type="text" name="nom_anti" id="nom_anti"><br>

             <div id="vih" style="display: none;">
               <label>INICIA TARGA: &nbsp&nbsp: &nbsp&nbsp</label>SI <input type="radio" id="tasi" name="ta" value="1">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspNO <input type="radio" id="tano" name="ta" value="2"><br>

               <dir id="targa">
                <input type="date" id="ftarga" name="ftarga">
               </dir>

                <label>INICIA TPC &nbsp&nbsp: &nbsp&nbsp</label>SI <input type="radio" id="tpsi" name="tp" value="1">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspNO <input type="radio" id="tp" name="tp" value="2"><br>

               <dir id="tpc">
                <input type="date" id="ftpc" name="ftpc">
               </dir>
             </div>
            <label>ENFERMEDADES CONCONMITANTES</label>
           <input type="text" name="enfconcomitantes">

        <div id="botoness1">     
            <div class="btnenviarf2">
              <input type='submit' id='btnenviar' class='btnenviar' name='btnenviar' value='GUARDAR'>
           </div>       
        </div>

   </div> 


          <div id="resultado" >
          </div>    

  </form>

</div>



<div id="formulario_esquemamdr" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

    <form id="fromulariomdr" onsubmit="return guardarmdr1();" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">


             <legend>DATOS DEL PACIENTE: <?php echo $apellidop.' '.$apellidom.' '.$nombre.'&nbsp&nbsp|&nbsp&nbsp'.$tipo_tratamiento;?></legend>


<?php 

 //$resultado_modalida_ingreso = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM modalidad_de_ingreso where obs='$condicion_ingreso'");
 $resultado_tipo_resistencia  = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM tipo_resistencia_mdr");
  //$resultado_metodo   = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM metodo");
  $resultado_tratamiento_mdr = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM tratamiento_mdr  where obs='$condicion_ingreso'");

  $consulta_cingreso = "SELECT * FROM condicion_ingreso WHERE obs='2' ";
$resultado_ingreso = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_cingreso);
 ?>



     <div class="panel panel-warning">
      <div class="panel-heading text-center">ESQUEMA DE TRATAMIENTO</div>
      <div class="panel-body">


  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-10" >NUMERO DE CASO </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nro_caso" name="nro_caso" placeholder="NRO CASO .." autocomplete="off"  >
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-6" >FECHA DE INICIO DE TRATAMIENTO </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2"> 
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="infechainimdr" name="infechainimdr">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >ESQUEMA </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8"> 
      <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="ESTANDARIZADO" >ESTANDARIZADO</label>
       <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="EMPIRICO" >EMPIRICO </label>
       <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="INDIVIDUALIZADO" >INDIVIDUALIZADO</label>
      <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio"  value="XDR" >XDR </label>
       <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="APOYO RAM" >APOYO RAM</label>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >DURACION </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="tiempomdr" name="tiempomdr" placeholder="duracion ...." autocomplete="off"  onblur="obtenerfechafinmdr();">
    </div>   
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-6" >CONDICION DE INGRESO </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <select id="condicion_in"  name="condicion_ingreso"  >
  <option value="" disabled selected>CONDICION DE INGRESO </option>
                <?php    
    while ( $row = $resultado_ingreso->fetch_array() )    
    {
        ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo $row['cod_cingreso'] ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre_condicion_ingreso']; ?></option>

                                 <?php
    }    
    ?>      
                </select>
    </div>   
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradiotb">TB RESISTENTE CONFIRMADA </label>
       <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradiotb">SOSPECHA DE TB RESISTENTE </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >TIPO DE RESISTENCIA :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <select id="tipo_res"  name="tipo_res"  >
  <option value="" disabled selected>TIPO DE RESISTENCIA</option>
                <?php    
    while ( $row = $resultado_tipo_resistencia->fetch_array() )    
    {
        ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo $row['id_tipo_mdr'] ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></option>

                                 <?php
    }    
    ?>      
                </select>
    </div>   
  </div>



  <div id="fecha_fin1mdr">

  </div> 


         <input type='submit'  value='GUARDAR' onclick="guardarmdr1();">



      </div>
    </div>






 </form>


</div>





  <script>
      //  The function to change the class
      var changeClass = function (r,className1,className2) {
        var regex = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s+)" + className1 + "(?:\\s+|$)");
        if( regex.test(r.className) ) {
          r.className = r.className.replace(regex,' '+className2+' ');
          }
          else{
          r.className = r.className.replace(new RegExp("(?:^|\\s+)" + className2 + "(?:\\s+|$)"),' '+className1+' ');
          }
          return r.className;
      };  

      //  Creating our button in JS for smaller screens
      var menuElements = document.getElementById('menu');
      menuElements.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin','<button type="button" id="menutoggle" class="navtoogle" aria-hidden="true"><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-menu"> </i> Menu</button>');

      //  Toggle the class on click to show / hide the menu
      document.getElementById('menutoggle').onclick = function() {
        changeClass(this, 'navtoogle active', 'navtoogle');
      }

      // http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/08/responsive-retina-ready-menu/comment-page-2/#comment-438918
      document.onclick = function(e) {
        var mobileButton = document.getElementById('menutoggle'),
          buttonStyle =  mobileButton.currentStyle ? mobileButton.currentStyle.display : getComputedStyle(mobileButton, null).display;

        if(buttonStyle === 'block' && e.target !== mobileButton && new RegExp(' ' + 'active' + ' ').test(' ' + mobileButton.className + ' ')) {
          changeClass(mobileButton, 'navtoogle active', 'navtoogle');
        }
      }
    </script>


  </body>
  </html>
```

**parte donde esta mi problema**

```
    <div id="formulario_esquemamdr" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

    <form id="fromulariomdr" onsubmit="return guardarmdr1();" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">


             <legend>DATOS DEL PACIENTE: <?php echo $apellidop.' '.$apellidom.' '.$nombre.'&nbsp&nbsp|&nbsp&nbsp'.$tipo_tratamiento;?></legend>


<?php 

 //$resultado_modalida_ingreso = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM modalidad_de_ingreso where obs='$condicion_ingreso'");
 $resultado_tipo_resistencia  = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM tipo_resistencia_mdr");
  //$resultado_metodo   = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM metodo");
  $resultado_tratamiento_mdr = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM tratamiento_mdr  where obs='$condicion_ingreso'");

  $consulta_cingreso = "SELECT * FROM condicion_ingreso WHERE obs='2' ";
$resultado_ingreso = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_cingreso);
 ?>



     <div class="panel panel-warning">
      <div class="panel-heading text-center">ESQUEMA DE TRATAMIENTO</div>
      <div class="panel-body">


  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-10" >NUMERO DE CASO </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nro_caso" name="nro_caso" placeholder="NRO CASO .." autocomplete="off"  >
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-6" >FECHA DE INICIO DE TRATAMIENTO </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2"> 
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="infechainimdr" name="infechainimdr">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >ESQUEMA </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8"> 
      <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="ESTANDARIZADO" >ESTANDARIZADO</label>
       <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="EMPIRICO" >EMPIRICO </label>
       <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="INDIVIDUALIZADO" >INDIVIDUALIZADO</label>
      <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio"  value="XDR" >XDR </label>
       <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="APOYO RAM" >APOYO RAM</label>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >DURACION </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="tiempomdr" name="tiempomdr" placeholder="duracion ...." autocomplete="off"  onblur="obtenerfechafinmdr();">
    </div>   
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-6" >CONDICION DE INGRESO </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <select id="condicion_in"  name="condicion_ingreso"  >
  <option value="" disabled selected>CONDICION DE INGRESO </option>
                <?php    
    while ( $row = $resultado_ingreso->fetch_array() )    
    {
        ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo $row['cod_cingreso'] ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre_condicion_ingreso']; ?></option>

                                 <?php
    }    
    ?>      
                </select>
    </div>   
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradiotb">TB RESISTENTE CONFIRMADA </label>
       <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradiotb">SOSPECHA DE TB RESISTENTE </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >TIPO DE RESISTENCIA :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <select id="tipo_res"  name="tipo_res"  >
  <option value="" disabled selected>TIPO DE RESISTENCIA</option>
                <?php    
    while ( $row = $resultado_tipo_resistencia->fetch_array() )    
    {
        ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo $row['id_tipo_mdr'] ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></option>

                                 <?php
    }    
    ?>      
                </select>
    </div>   
  </div>



  <div id="fecha_fin1mdr">

  </div> 


         <input type='submit' id='btnenviar' class='btnenviar' name='btnenviar' value='GUARDAR' onclick="guardarmdr1();">



      </div>
    </div>






 </form>


</div>
```

**funcion del boton**

```
function guardarmdr1(){

  $.ajax({
     type : "POST",
     url : "traguardarmdr1.php",
     data : $("#fromulariomdr").serialize(),
     success : function(data){
        $("#resultadomdr").html(data);  
     }
  })

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Que muestra la consulta de errores?

Answer (score 0):

Agrégale al `Form` la opción **Action** y ahí pones el nombre de tu archivo `PHP`, una vez le des al `Button`, el formulario te llevara a él junto con los datos que suministraste por el método `POST`.

Seria así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="modificar.php">

<input type="text" placeholder="Nombre del Hijo" name="hijo">
<input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email">

<button type="submit">ENVIAR</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```